# Read Socket stream data and read first 2 bytes, find rest of message length

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, bytearrayinputstream

How to read first 2 bytes from input stream and convert 2 bytes data into actual int length value, then read and copy the rest of message into byte array.
The rest of data array should be defined after reading first 2 bytes from the stream, does anyone know efficient logic?

Comment: @ejp voting is anonymous, no explanation necessary.  Asking for explanations is noise and to be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `DataInputStream.` Use the `readUnsignedShort()` method to return the length word, then the `readFully()` method to read the following data.

Comment: thank you very much for your all the encouragements. if I receive multiple messages from the input stream, don't I need to use while loop?? because continuously data flowing from the socket.

Comment: That will only work if the size is at most (2^15)-1. readShort will return a negative number if the size is greater than Short.MAX_VALUE

Comment: @pradeekrathnayaka Of course you need a loop. Each iteration should do the above.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for that. I never noticed that readUnsignedShort method, always did the bitwise &0xFFFF masking to convert it. This is clearer for the reader. +1

Answer (score 1):

This creates a string from a byte array. Adapt as needed.

```
InputStream in;
try {
    in = socket.getInputStream();
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);

    int len = dis.readInt();
    byte[] data = new byte[len];
    if (len > 0) {
       dis.readFully(data);
    }           
    String sReturn = new String(data); 
}
```

Comment: Almost, but that reads 4 bytes of length information, not two.